# ServiceStack.Text JSON parsing on .Net 4.0

Tags: c#, json, servicestack

H chaps,
I am trying to use ServiceStack.Text for JSON parsing (it seems to be performing better than JSON.Net in various benchmarks I have seen). But I am not getting the results I am expecting. The class I am attempting to deserialize looks like this:

```
[DataContract]
public class RpcRequest<T>
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    [DataMember(Name="id")]
    public String Id;

    [JsonProperty("method")]
    [DataMember(Name="method")]
    public String Method;

    [JsonProperty("params")]
    [DataMember(Name="params")]
    public T Params;

    [JsonIgnore]
    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public Policy Policy;
}
```

And I am invoking the parser like this

```
public static class Json
{
    public static T Deserialize<T>(string serialized)
    {
        return TypeSerializer.DeserializeFromString<T>(serialized);
    }
}
...
RpcRequest<Params> myRequeset = Json.Deserialize(packet);
```

However I am getting an instance back from that call which has none of the values set. ie `Id`, `Method` and `Params` are all null. Am I using this API correctly?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems that ServiceStack does not support public fields, only public properties. So if I change my model object to the following it all works.

```
[DataContract]
public class RpcRequest<T>
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    [DataMember(Name="id")]
    public String Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("method")]
    [DataMember(Name="method")]
    public String Method { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("params")]
    [DataMember(Name="params")]
    public T Params { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public Policy Policy { get; set; }
}
```

Note the addition of getters and setters to each property.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want `JsonSerializer` instead of `TypeSerializer`.

`TypeSerializer` is a new-fangled JSV format that Mr Mythz details on his blog here: http://www.servicestack.net/mythz_blog/?p=176

Comment: You are quite right, I did want JsonSerializer. TypeSerializer doesn't produce valid JSON. However this wasn't quite the cause of my issues